# Hard disk partitions

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, 17.04

I have to install Ubuntu 17.04 on my computer. On the computer in question, I have a data partition. During the installation of Ubuntu 17.04, does the option to "Erase disk and install Ubuntu" also delete the empty partition, or leave it as an empty disk partition?

*Original question (Italian)*

Avrei una domanda.
Io devo installare ubuntu 17.04 sul mio computer.
Io sul computer in questione, ho una partizione di dati.
Il mio quesito è:
se durante l'installazione di ubuntu 17.04 selezione l'opzione cancella disco e installa ubuntu, cancella anche la partizione dei dati che è vuota oppure la lascia come partizione del disco vuota?
Grazie per la collaorazione.

Comment: Yes, "ease and install..." will do just that. You need to choose "something else" to select a different partitioning scheme if you need to keep and/or reuse partitions.

Answer (score 4):

"Erase disk" erases the disk .. totally. The disk will be partitioned in default Ubuntu way. If you want to control which partitions are used, choose "Something Else" and set up your own partitioning, here you can leave your data-partition untouched, if you want.